# multiple alignment inside cases environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, cases

How can i use multiple alignment inside cases environment? i tired to use alignat, align* ... but it seems that they dont work inside equation environment.

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:13}
\begin{aligned}
W_{ij} = \begin{cases}
tf_{ij} \times \log \left( \frac{N}{n_i} \right) &if\quad &AW_i = 0\\
AW_i \times tf_{ij} \times \log \left( N/ n_i \right) &if\quad 0<&AW_i<1\\
\left(1 + \log \left( AW_i \right) \right) \times tf_{ij} \times \log 
\left(\frac{N}{n_i} \right) &if\quad &AW_i \geq 1
\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

when i insert second & for each case it returns error !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, use only one `&` symbol per row. If this were my document, I'd stick with the default layout for the right-hand column of the `cases` environment, which is left alignment of the material. For sure, you can't used an `aligned` environment to achieve your formatting objective.

Two additional comments: (i) Use `\left` and `\right` only sparingly. (ii) Try to keep your notation consistent. At times, you use `\frac{N}{n_i}`, while at others you write `N/n_i`. In the present context, I'd use the latter, i.e., inline-fraction notation.

[image]

Note also that I changed all instances of `tf_{ij}` in your code to `\mathit{tf}_{\!ij}`, both to tighten up the appearance of `tf` and to "snug up" the subscript term to its base. If you have a lot of instances of `tf_{ij}`, you may want to create a shorthand macro, say, `\newcommand\tfij{\mathit{tf}_{\!ij}}`, and then replace all instances of `tf_{ij}` in your document with `\tfij`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' env. and '\text' macro
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:13}
W_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
  \mathit{tf}_{\!ij} \times \log(N/n_i) 
     & \text{if $AW_i = 0$}\\
  AW_i \times \mathit{tf}_{\!ij} \times \log(N/n_i) 
     & \text{if $0<AW_i<1$}\\
  (1 + \log AW_i) \times \mathit{tf}_{\!ij} \times \log(N/n_i) 
     & \text{if $AW_i \geq 1$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: For the case at hand (pun intended), what you may want to think about, in terms of changing the layout, is to right-align the material in the *first* column of the `cases` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' env. and '\text' macro
\newcommand\tfij{\mathit{tf}_{\!ij}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:13a}
W_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
  \hfill \tfij \times \log(N/n_i) 
     & \text{if $AW_i = 0$}\\
  \hfill AW_i \times \tfij \times \log(N/n_i) 
     & \text{if $0<AW_i<1$}\\
  (1 + \log AW_i) \times \tfij \times \log(N/n_i) 
     & \text{if $AW_i \geq 1$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

---

*Second addendum*, to address the OP's follow-up comment: To achieve the desired special alignment of the material in the second column of the `cases` environment, I suggest you use `\phantom` statements in rows 1 and 3.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'cases' env. and '\text' macro
\newcommand\tfij{\mathit{tf}_{\!ij}}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:13aa}
W_{ij} = 
\begin{cases}
  \hfill \tfij \times \log(N/n_i) 
     & \text{if $\phantom{0<{}}AW_i = 0$}\\
  \hfill AW_i \times \tfij \times \log(N/n_i) 
     & \text{if $0<AW_i<1$}\\
  (1 + \log AW_i) \times \tfij \times \log(N/n_i) 
     & \text{if $\phantom{0<{}}AW_i \geq 1$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your comments. But i would like to have two alignments symbol for each case. One before "if" and another one before "AW".

Comment: @danitiger33 - I've posted an addendum to show how your specific alignment needs might be met. Incidentally, IMNSHO, `$0=AW_i$` would look better than `$\phantom{0<{}}AW_i = 0$`.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `cases` environment as defined by amsmath is basically just

```
\left\lbrace
\array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
...
\endarray \right.
```

it is no great task to use an explicit `array` environment with whatever columns and alignment you want.

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:13}
W_{ij} = \left\lbrace\,
\begin{array}{@{}r@{\quad}l@{}l@{}}
tf_{ij} \times \log (N/n_i) &\text{if}\quad &AW_i = 0\\
AW_i \times tf_{ij} \times \log (N/n_i) &\text{if}\quad 0<{}&AW_i<1\\
\bigl(1 + \log(AW_i) \bigr) \times tf_{ij} \times \log 
(N/n_i) &\text{if}\quad &AW_i \geq 1
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
```

Note the `0<{}&` to get the binary-relation spacing correct. I used right-alignment as per @Mico's suggestion, but assumed `tf` and `AW` are products, not single variables.